# Teamcity and xcode: Cannot use Xcode for workspace

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm getting an error when i'm try to use workspace in Temacity. "Cannot use Xcode 3 for workspace. Please either specify a path to the project or change Xcode version." How do i change Xcode version or specify a path to the project if its already in the right path? or what should i do? Please help. 
[image: Doesn't work for workspace]

But it does work for project.

[image: but it works for project]

Comment: Do you use Xcode 3? Have you tried other version?

Comment: Where do i change that? by build agent is running Xcode 5

Comment: Did you try to Check/reparse project or setting path to Xcode manually?

Comment: I tried to do Check/reparse. Same thing. It works fine when i choose xcodeproj, but i need workspace because its include cocoa pods files. Can you give me example of path to Xcode?

Comment: I'm guessing but most probably in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: No, doesn't work. Same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60474/discussion-between-pashan-and-dejan-dakic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End up using script and Scheme. Worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use scheme-based build with .xcworkspace.